# Adding a new execution environment in Eclipse 4.3 in Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

When you install a brand new Eclipse, in a brand new workspace, it find automatically the JRE, and fill the Execution environment.

But if you had latter a new JVM, it's not possible any more to add an execution environment.

The discovered path are wrong too, many jar are missing, and needs to be installed manually.

Does some one know how Eclipse build this list or how to force a re-discovery ?

I tried that with Eclipse 4.3, on Mac OS 10.8.4, trying to install JDK 1.7.0_40.

Comment: First you add the JRE to the list of installed JREs, then you assign it to an Execution Environment reference.

Comment: I didn't have a problem, JRE path on Mac OS is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: I think a restart might be need, jdk1.7.0_40 in now in execution environments. It just appears 24 hours latter...

Answer (score 0):

If the list of Execution Environments you are seeing is out of date, you may need to update it by installing the latest version of the **API Tools Execution Environment Descriptions** item from  http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3

For details see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments under **Installing Execution Environment Descriptions**)

If you are using Kepler (Eclipse 4.3) you may also need to enable JDK 8 support:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler (see [upgrade eclipse to java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619262/upgrade-eclipse-to-java-8))