# upgrade eclipse to java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, upgrade

I am trying to update my eclipse environment to java 8. I installed the jdk and jre version 8.  I also did this:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

then in project -> properties -> java build path -> JRE system libraries -> edit -> execution environment -> JavaSE-1.8(unbound) which is the only option that has java 8 in its name. but when I select it it says : No JREs in workspace compatible with specified execution environment: JavaSE-1.8

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Go to `Window | Preferences`.  Then under `Java | Installed JREs`, click `"Add"`, click `"Standard VM"`, then `"Next"`, then `"Directory"`, and find the location where you installed `JDK 1.8`.

Lastly, make sure the checkbox next to it, on the list of installed JREs, is switched on.

Comment: could you explain the difference between Standard VM/ Execution Environment VM?

Comment: @avck You'll probably get a good answer to that if you ask it as a separate question, so that a larger number of people see it.

Comment: If you use SDKMAN, the locations are $HOME/.sdkman/candidates/java/...

Answer (score 8):

In OS X, go to `Preference` and choose `Java | Installed JREs`. Then click `search` it would show JAVA SE 8 if you have already installed JAVA SDK 8.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I would like to precise something. If you installed java8 with apt-get like me, the jdk is add to /usr/lib/jvm.

Comment: Should have been comment