# Eclipse - Installing a new JRE (Java SE 8 1.8.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I am trying to install Java 8.

What I have done so far:

- installed the latest version of Eclipse
- downloaded and installed Java SE Runtime Environment 8 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html
- tried to follow this -> [upgrade eclipse to java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619262/upgrade-eclipse-to-java-8) without a happy ending

The error I get as soon as I create the project:

> Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]' in project 'JackTest' Build Path Problem

Any idea? Can someone tell me what to do step by step?

Comment: do you have multiple java versions installed? Also check Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. The 1.8 JRE should be selected n this page.

Comment: the only JRE installed at the moment is Java SE 6 1.6.0

Comment: You need to install JDK 8. It will be better if you also uninstall old Java versions.

Comment: Does “I downloaded Java SE Runtime Environment 8” imply that you also *installed* it? Also, “the latest version of Eclipse” is `Eclipse Luna` which does not need the patches for `Eclipse Kepler`. It should work with Java 8 out-of-the-box.

Comment: Means that I installed it. And Eclipse Luna does not work out of the box, I even tried to uninstall it, re-download it and re-install it. Did not work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can have many java versions in your system.

I think you should add the java 8 in yours JREs installed or edit.

Take a look my screen:

[image]

If you click in edit (check your java 8 path):

[image]

Comment: It worked, I needed to know the exact path where to put that damn  thing